# Tailwind w-100 is larger than the screen for Chrome but works fine for other browsers

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

So i am using tailwind with React. `justify-center` is off-center. If i use `justify-end`, some of the items do not show. I do not know what is the issue. I tried setting the width to `w-full` or `w-screen` but it is the same thing

It is working fine on Firefox and Safari but not on Chrome.

here is my `Navbar.jsx`

```
export default function Navbar() {
  return (
    <div className="fixed bg-bg-dark w-full">
      <div className="flex flex-row justify-center">
        <h1 className=" text-2xl text-accent">DabberGame</h1>
        <form className="">
          <input type="text" />
        </form>
        <button className="text-white">Post Listing</button>
        <p className="text-white">|</p>
        <button className="text-white">Login</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is my `App.js`

```
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
function App() {
  return <Navbar />;
}

export default App;
```

here is the output:
[image]

Here is a second output if i use `justify-end`
[image]

I do not have any other code. It is just `Navbar.jsx` for now

Comment: How are you rendering the `<Navbar />`? Can you also share your `App.js` code.
Because this code is working fine, as yo can see in this [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-and-react-forked-zm5p03?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: i am adding an edit right now

Comment: Can't say this is chrome issue, the above sandbox is working just as good in chrome as well. I can't really reproduce this behavior with me.
You'd have to figure out the problem by going into the `inspect element` option.

Comment: Where are you importing Navbar? The current code should work perfectly without any other components in the way. Show the App.js code as well.